# Trying to slice a large css file Trying to slice a large css file (1,952,726 rows) to chances using Python

Tags: python, split, chunks

When I run the following command, I get an error:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

Endcustomers = "Resources/WESTCON_INTE_LTD_2024_01_GBP.csv"
Endcustomers_df = pd.read_csv(Endcustomers)
Endcustomers_df.head(3)

def split_csv_into_chunks(Endcustomers, 10000):
    # Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(Endcustomers)
    
    # Determine the total number of chunks needed
    total_chunks = len(df) // 500000 + 1
    
    # Split the DataFrame into chunks
    chunks = np.array_split(df, total_chunks)
    
    # Save each chunk as a separate CSV file
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        chunk.to_csv(f"{input_file}_chunk_{i+1}.csv", index=False)
        print(f"Chunk {i+1} saved.")
```

Error:
Cell In[16], line 1
def split_csv_into_chunks(Endcustomers,10000):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone help resolve this please? Thank you

Comment: What is the `10000` meant to be on that line?

Comment: Remove ", 10000" from *def split_csv_into_chunks(Endcustomers, 10000):* to avoid the syntax error. Also, what does this have to do with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on the definition of the function, you are receiving two arguments "Endcustomers" and "10000", which "10000" can't be an argument.

Fix:

```
def split_csv_into_chunks(Endcustomers):
```

Also you are using a variable called "input_file" which doesn't exists in your context.

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk.to_csv(f"INSERT_NAME_OF_FILE_chunk_{i+1}.csv", index=False)
    print(f"Chunk {i+1} saved.")
```

And you are not calling `split_csv_into_chunks` anywhere, do you have more code below?